# Why are the blocks out of order?

Tags: blockchain

When I look at blockchain.info or blockexplorer.com, it shows the latest blocks.

The most recent block, #283653, has time 2014-02-01 22:42:08.
The previous block, #283652, has time 2014-02-01 22:45:57.

So the previous block has a timestamp larger than the most recent block. How is this possible?